# difference between request header cache policy and response header

Tags: http, caching, amazon-web-services, header, amazon-s3

I have some js hosted on AWS. I want to cache it to not to pay extra for 304 GET request, but I'm puzzled why two headers are different.

```
Request Method:GET
Status Code:304 Not Modified
```

Request header of helper.js

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
If-Modified-Since:Tue, 20 Aug 2013 13:08:13 GMT
```

and response header

```
Age:4348
Cache-Control:max-age=604800
Connection:keep-alive
```

Why they are different? Does it mean that Cache-Control is wrong? I used Chrome console to get the headers.

Comment: I am a little bit confused. Are you asking why the server responded with different Cache-Control header even if you sent a Cache-Control header in the client side? I guess you are expecting that to happen?

Comment: Basically, I want to my js to be cached and what does it mean that those two have different cache-control

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that Cache-Control is wrong and it seems that your content is already cached. From the request headers, I understand that the first request was done at `Tue, 20 Aug 2013 13:08:13 GMT` as the browser indicates the server "hey, has the content changed since that time?". In return, the server responses with `304 Not Modified` header, indicating that the content has not been changed and it should be cached `604800` seconds more until revalidating it. Remember that the caching is done on server side. So, you may want to look at your server defitinitons on js files. Usually, in the deployment environment, I instruct my webserver to send cache header for *.js *.png etc. After configuring the web server for sending cache headers, it is the browser's work to take care of the rest. In that case, your browser works as expected.

You can look at [RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) for 304 response. You may also want to look at [this decent caching tutorial](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/). It should clear some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with Chrome. If you press Refresh button it invalidates the cache, but if you press Enter in address bar it gets the resources from cache.